# Wrong version of function getting called in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am working on retrieving Inception V3 model's top layer in Keras/Tensorflow (in Jupyter Notebook).

I could retrieve the Inception V3 model and its weights correctly.
Now, I am trying to get Fully Connected layer (top layer) using following code snippet.

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights=weights)
base_model.get_layer('flatten')
```

However, the function is failed saying 
**"ValueError: No such layer: flatten"**

When I looked at the stacktrace, get_layer() function from topology.py is getting called which is under **'keras/engine'**.

Rather than this function, get_layer() function from models.py directly under **keras** should have been called.

What possibly can be the problem? How can I force Python to call the correct version? Or is there any other way to get the weights from InceptionV3 model?

---

Just tried enumerating `base_model.layers` list contents and found that the name of the layers are different and no layer named **flatten** is found.
So I replaced flatten with the last presumably FC layer named '**mixed10**' and the code worked.

Is this the right thing to do? or I am doing something improper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that name of these layers keep on changing. So best way is to enumerate all the layer names using `Model.layers[].name` or `Model.summary()` and use whichever name you want that is listed in the output.

Answer (score 0):

`InceptionV3` model has no `'flatten'` layer

to get the top Fully connected layer you can just use

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights=weights, include_top=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this case, we need to set `include_top=True` right?